# How to add CSS & JS to Docker image

Tags: javascript, html, css, docker, dockerfile

I've got 3 scripts

`index.html` `style.css` and `script.js`

```js
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
  $('.torch').css({
    'top': event.pageY,
    'left': event.pageX
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {  
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/6SLzBEY.jpg") no-repeat left top;
  background-size: cover;  
  overflow: hidden;
    
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text h1{
  color: #011718;
    margin-top: -200px;
  font-size: 15em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: -5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), -10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4), -15px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text h2{
  color: black;
  font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: -5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -150px;
    font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text h3{
  color: white;
    margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: -5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin-top: -40px;
    font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.torch {
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999em #000000f7;
    opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 2px #000,
            0 0 20px 4px rgba(13,13,10,0.2);  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <h1>404</h1>
    <h2>Hello Foo</h2>
  <h3>Sorry you're lost.. Come back later</h3>
</div>
<div class="torch"></div>
```

All in a `src` directory.

I'm trying to bundle this into a docker image in order to create a 404 error page.
I able to build the image and it renders the `index.html` page but the CSS isn't loading and being new to this I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM nginx:stable
COPY src/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Your html needs to reference the css and js with `script` and `link` tags

Comment: I've tried adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` and `<script src="script.js"></script>`but its not rendering. 

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: update the post with working html, you should be able to test your html in a browser for this example... there's nothing wrong with your dockerfile

Comment: Looks like there might be a problem with loading CSS in docker. 
I'm able to run this code snippet in the browser and it works as expected but not when bundled into a container.

Not sure what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with docker but the html.  You haven't included your script.js and the html you posted is just a fragment of a page, a not full [html5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) page

Assuming you have this directory structure, it will work once you include your js

```
./Dockerfile
./src
./src/index.html
./src/script.js
./src/style.css
```

Just run

```
docker build -t demo-nginx .
docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name demonginx demo-nginx && docker attach demonginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory to **VOLUME: ** `VOLUME ["/usr/share/nginx/html"]` in docker and run container with `-v ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html` option